# Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections

Tags: firefox, proxy, mac

I am new to the TOR browser, I have downloaded and installed it on my mac. When I open it up and go to search something, it comes up with "Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections." I have gone into the settings but I can't figure out how to get around this problem. I don't know a proxy to use. 
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your tor process seems to be in bootstrapping phase and it's "not ready to serve" yet, please attach a log to your answer. Just give it some time - it can be even 5-7 minutes for a first run.